# Transformar formulario HTML a JSON

Tags: javascript

Queria saber como puedo transformar los valores de "Name" y "Age" en un objeto json al darle al button, traves de un objeto js.

```
<div class='container'>
<h3>Form</h3>
<div class='container'>
    <label>Name:</label><input type='text'/>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <label>Age:</label><input type='text'/>
</div>
<div class='form-actions'>
    <button>Convert to JSON</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Tienes algun javascript y quieres transformar todo de HTML o solo "Name" y "Age"?

Comment: Solo name y age

Comment: @al2122 sin Javascript no vamos a llevar a ninguna parte

Answer (score 0):

Puedes dar los `<input>` y `<button>` un `id` y usar `document.getElementById` para obtener "name", "age" y el botón.
Después `addEventListener('click', () => {})` para obtener el evento de clic.
`.value` te dará el valor que escribe el usuario de "name" y "age".

```js
const name = document.getElementById('name');
const age = document.getElementById('age');
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const json = document.getElementById('json');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const obj = {
    name: name.value,
    age: age.value
  };
  json.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj);
});
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <h3>Form</h3>
  <div class='container'>
    <label>Name:</label><input id="name" type='text' />
  </div>
  <div class='container'>
    <label>Age:</label><input id="age" type='text' />
  </div>
  <div class='form-actions'>
    <button id="btn">Convert to JSON</button>
    <p id="json"></p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias crear un script que al presionar el boton, tome los valores actuales de cada input, y los retorne dentro un objeto javascript.

Luego solo quedaria aplicar `JSON.stringify(Tu objeto)`, y ya estaria.

Para capturar el evento del click del boton lo podrias hacer con un `.addEventListener('click', function(){})`.

Donde function es lo que te explique al principio. Y por lo que veo tendrias que cambiar tu HTML agregando id's a tus elementos para poder identificarlos mas rapido y facil en tu script.

Cualquier consulta aca estoy.